# Retry period after an unhandled exception in a Workflow

Tags: workflow, workflow-foundation-4, workflowservice

Currently in our workflow application if it encounters an unhandled exception it will reload the workflow from the most recently persisted state and try again. Are there any ways to configure how this works exactly? If a service is down for example the workflow will reload around every second and try to run again which when there are multiple workflows all doing the same thing can result in thousands of exceptions per minute.

I think that using the timeToPersist and timeToUnload properties on workflowIdle might have something to do with this. Currently we have this set to:

If I set timeToUnload to 1 minute will that mean the workflow will only be able to retry once every minute?

Answer (score 0):

TimeToPersist and TimeToUnload won't come into play here- those values determine how long a workflow has to be idle before being persisted/unloaded.

You can probably use WorkflowApplication.OnUnhandledException to create a catch-all exception handler (assuming you're using this class to create workflows).

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.activities.workflowapplication.onunhandledexception.aspx

Comment: These are IIS hosted xamlx workflows so that is a no go - it isn't about handling the exceptions - everything there works 100% the way I want it to, I log the exceptions using workflow tracking. The only issue is that the workflows get picked back up again and retried immediately. If I have thousands of running workflows and a service goes down I can have thousands of attempts a minute (and therefore thousands of failures) which then puts a lot of extra load on the server. I would like to set it so that the workflows will wait a minute or so before retrying.